# Is there a way to center an element and then have another element directly to the right of it?

Tags: html, css, center

I'm trying to center a text element and then have an explanatory "what is this?" next to it. However when I type in the "what is this?" part, it obviously moves the original text element off center. Is there a way to fix this using CSS or HTML?

Comment: Can you post your HTML and css or JSfiddle? It will be easier to answer.

Comment: Give your text element as `float:left;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap the text-element that needs to be centered in a div and style `position:absolute` to that div using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example without having to assign width to any elements. This should work fine with any length of text thrown at it.

http://codepen.io/ay13/pen/GJKawz

HTML and CSS:

```css
    h1 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    h1 a {
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<h1>
    <span>Centered Text <a href="#">What is this?</a></span>
</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you can do it:
http://jsfiddle.net/wgbs4asv/1/

You basically need to have the right-side "what is this?" div inside of the main div (and before the main div's content), but with the right-side "what is this?" div's CSS set to:

```
float: right;
width: 100px;
margin-right: -100px;
position: relative;
```

(but using whatever width you want, and with a negative margin-right to match the width). The width would offset the main div's position, but then the negative margin with the `position: relative` brings it back.

Answer (score 1):

It will be better if you share your code.

but anyway, you will need to position the text relative and then add the explanatory in it and position it to absolute, here is the code to make things clear.

```css
.parent {
    width: 80%;
    background: lightblue;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightslategrey;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.text {
    position: relative;
    width: fit-content;
    background: lightcoral;
    text-align: center;
}
.explanatory { 
    width: max-content;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
 <div class="parent">
        <span class="container">
            <p class="text">text text text 
                <span class="explanatory">what is this?</span>
            </p>
            
        </span>
    </div>
```